# Execute bash script from PHP with arguments

Tags: php, bash, cron

I have a PHP script that will be run as cron on Ubuntu server.

I am trying to execute a bash script from PHP script like this :

```
    exec(escapeshellarg('/bin/bash ') . escapeshellarg("/home/monu/myBash.sh") . escapeshellarg("var1") . escapeshellarg("var2") .escapeshellarg("var3"));
```

When I run "**`php myPHP.php`**" in terminal as user (monu) then I get error like this :

```
    sh: 1: /bin/bash /home/monu/myBash.sh var1 var2 var3: not found
```

The contents of **myBash.sh** are something like :

```
    export CLASSPATH=./:./lib/xp.jar:./lib/ojdbc14.jar:./lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar:./lib/log4j.properties:./lib/log4j.xml

    cd someDir
    ./install.sh $A $B $C $D
    cd ..
```

When I manually execute the BASH script from command line it works as expected.

I've even tried **`system()`** and **`shell_exec()`** but still no luck.

How should I call this BASH script from PHP script to make it work, any hints ?

Comment: That's because your apache/php user doesn't have permission to access your home folder.

Comment: @Jon, I am running the PHP script in terminal for debugging purposes while logged in as user (monu). So I guess file permissions are not causing problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`escapeshellarg()` should be used on *each argument*, not the command as a whole.

```
exec(escapeshellarg('/bin/bash') . ' ' . escapeshellarg("/home/monu/myBash.sh") . ' ' . escapeshellarg(...));
```

Comment: Thanks for the head's up, I've updated the code but still the error persists.